# Ifelse condition in data table's set function

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to generate new columns in a data table based on multiple pair-wise columns in the same data table.  For example, newcol1 = b1/a1, newcol2 = b2/a2, etc.

I can do it in a way that I think will be slow if the actual data table has millions of row.  What I did is

```
dt = data.table(
  a1 = c(1, 0, 3, 4, 5), 
  a2 = c(1, 2, 3, 0, 5), 
  b1 = c(6:10),
  b2 = c(6:10) 
)

for (i in 1:2) {
  ind1<-paste("pay", i, sep="")
  ind2<-paste("a", i, sep="")
  ind3<-paste("b", i, sep="")

  dt[[ind1]]<-ifelse(dt[[ind2]]<=0, 100, round((dt[[ind3]]/dt[[ind2]])*100,5))
}
```

I tried to improve using `set` function.  It works. But when I wrap a `ifelse` condition, it fails.

Codes below works:

```
ind1<-paste("pay", 1:2, sep="")
ind2<-paste("a", 1:2, sep="")
ind3<-paste("b", 1:2, sep="")

dt[, (ind1):=NA]
set(dt, j=ind1, value=round((dt[, ind3, with=FALSE] / dt[, ind2, with=FALSE])*100,5))
```

But the one below with `ifelse` doesn't work:

```
set(dt, j=ind1, value=ifelse(dt[, ind2, with=FALSE]<=0, 100, 
                             round((dt[, ind3, with=FALSE] / dt[, ind2, with=FALSE])*100,5)))
```

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

My desired output should look like this:

```
+----+----+----+----+--------+--------+
| a1 | a2 | b1 | b2 |  pay1  |  pay2  |
+----+----+----+----+--------+--------+
|  1 |  1 |  6 |  6 | 600.00 | 600.00 |
|  0 |  2 |  7 |  7 | 100.00 | 350.00 |
|  3 |  3 |  8 |  8 | 266.67 | 266.67 |
|  4 |  0 |  9 |  9 | 225.00 | 100.00 |
|  5 |  5 | 10 | 10 | 200.00 | 200.00 |
+----+----+----+----+--------+--------+
```

Comment: can you add your desired output?

Comment: also, how many columns do you have?

Comment: I'm confused about what you're trying to do. Why can't you do `dt[, ``:=``(newcol1 = b1/a1, newcol2 = b2/a2)]` (remove duplicated ticks by single ticks)? This will be fast and you won't have to worry about *"I think will be slow if the actual data table has millions of row"*.

Comment: @VitaliAvagyan I have added an example of desired output in the post. Right now, I have 12 columns (6  pairs) from which I need to create 6 new columns.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Thanks for your suggestion which will work well for a few new columns.  But I want to be prepared for datasets in which I need to create a lots of new columns.

Comment: @Gregor Ah I was looking for that:-) I read something about escaping with triple backticks which didn't work then gave up. `\`:=\`` works. Horray!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick fix after running your current code would be to replace `Inf` values with 100

```
dt[dt == Inf] <- 100
```

However, if you want to correct the output in the first step itself, we can use `Map`

```
library(data.table)
dt[, (ind1) := Map(function(x, y) ifelse(x <= 0 , 1, y/x) * 100, 
               dt[, ind2, with = FALSE], dt[, ind3, with = FALSE])]

dt
#   a1 a2 b1 b2     pay1     pay2
#1:  1  1  6  6 600.0000 600.0000
#2:  0  2  7  7 100.0000 350.0000
#3:  3  3  8  8 266.6667 266.6667
#4:  4  0  9  9 225.0000 100.0000
#5:  5  5 10 10 200.0000 200.0000
```

Comment: With `Map`, wouldn't this work with `if`/`else` as well? (meaning: singles, not vectors).

Comment: Will it? We are checking for `x <=0` in `Map` where `x` is a vector of numeric values.

Comment: You're right, my bad, the `dt[, ind2, with = FALSE]` is a table with two columns, so each `x` is a vector. Sorry for the mis-comment, I should have held the comment until the ability to play with it.

Comment: @Ronak Shah elegant solution and thanks for introducing me to `map`.  this is something I have never seen before.

Answer (score 3):

Your data set strikes me as a long data set in wide form. If you have no compelling reason to keep it that way, I would first reshape your data into long form (keeping with `data.table`, that means `melt`ing):

```
dt = melt(
  dt,
  measure.vars = patterns(a = '^a', b = '^b'),
  variable.name = 'idx'
)
head(dt)[]
#    idx a  b
# 1:   1 1  6
# 2:   1 0  7
# 3:   1 3  8
# 4:   1 4  9
# 5:   1 5 10
# 6:   2 1  6
```

On the `melt`ed `data.table`, your problem becomes much more straightforward:

```
dt[ , pay := ifelse(a <= 0, 100, 100*round(b/a, 5L))][1:6]
 #   idx a  b     pay
# 1:   1 1  6 600.000
# 2:   1 0  7 100.000
# 3:   1 3  8 266.667
# 4:   1 4  9 225.000
# 5:   1 5 10 200.000
# 6:   2 1  6 600.000
```

Note that I've replaced `ifelse` with the newly contributed `fifelse`, which is (for another short while) only available in the development version; see the [Installation wiki](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) for instructions on installing this. It should work (mostly) as a drop-in replacement for `ifelse`, though, so `ifelse` will do just fine, but slower on large data.

If you'd rather stick with the same data shape, you can `melt`, add, reshape like so:

```
dt[ , melt(.SD, measure.vars = patterns(a = '^a', b = '^b'), variable.name = 'idx')
    ][ , pay := fifelse(a <= 0, 100, 100*round(b/a, 5L))
       ][ , dcast(.SD, rowid(idx) ~ idx, value.var = c('a', 'b', 'pay'))]
#    idx a_1 a_2 b_1 b_2   pay_1   pay_2
# 1:   1   1   1   6   6 600.000 600.000
# 2:   2   0   2   7   7 100.000 350.000
# 3:   3   3   3   8   8 266.667 266.667
# 4:   4   4   0   9   9 225.000 100.000
# 5:   5   5   5  10  10 200.000 200.000
```

You can delete the dummy column `idx` by using `:= NULL` and use `sep = ''` in `dcast` to return the same column names.

Or, you could do this but define the new columns directly:

```
dt[ , c('pay1', 'pay2') := 
        .SD[ , melt(.SD, measure.vars = patterns(a = '^a', b = '^b'), variable.name = 'idx')
             ][ , pay := fifelse(a <= 0, 100, 100*round(b/a, 5L))
                ][ , dcast(.SD, rowid(idx) ~ idx, value.var = c('pay'))
                   ][ , idx := NULL]][]
```